# Prompted when attempting to move a file in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10

When I attempt to move file in Windows Explorer, I'm prompted to confirm the action.

This occurs with:

- drag and drop (when the mouse button is released)
- cut and paste (on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)
- files dragged **from** the Recycle Bin

These operations are NOT affected:

- drag and drop **copies**
- files dragged **to** the Recycle Bin
- `move` command and `move-item` cmdlet

Where is this behavior defined?  Is there a registry entry for this or is it a group policy?  Which one?

Comment: This behavior is defined by (and therefore in) Windows. It is very largely not subject to turning ON and OFF because the actions and results are part of normal human behavior. You get prompted because the result may be something you do not want.

Comment: @John, this behavior is unique to this company's workstations and not part of Windows default behavior.

Comment: Must be something in group policy.